# Usar modal en distintas vista en mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, modal

Hola tengo un proyecto mvc en .net5 en c# y no puedo usar un modal en otra vista.
En la vista Index tengo este codigo

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="#nuevoAlumno" data-bs-toggle="modal">Nuevo Alumno</a>
</div>
```

Quiero q cuando haga click en "Nuevo Alumno" vaya al controlador "DetalleAlumno" y en esa vista abra el modal.

El controlador es éste

```
     [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DetalleAlumno(string dni)
    {
        AlumnoCarreraDto modelo_alumno = new AlumnoCarreraDto();

        ViewBag.Accion = "Agregar Alumno";

        if (dni != null)
        {
            modelo_alumno.Carrera = await _servicioCarreras.TraerListaCarrera();

            modelo_alumno.Alumno = await _servicioAlumnos.DetalleAlumno(dni);
            ViewBag.Accion = "Editar Alumno";
        }
        return View(modelo_alumno);
    }
```

Y en la vista de este controlador (DetalleAlumno) tengo este codigo q no se está ejecutando.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        @ViewBag.Accion
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        @if (ViewBag.Accion == "Agregar Alumno")
        {
            <div class="modal fade" id="nuevoAlumno" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            Agregar Alumno
                            <form asp-action="AgregarAlumno" asp-controller="Alumno" method="post">
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <label class="form-label">Dni</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Alumno.Dni" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Alumno.Nombre" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <label class="form-label">Apellido</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Alumno.Apellido" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <label class="form-label">Tel</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Alumno.Tel" required title="Ingresa 0 si no tienes un telefono para ingresar" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <label class="form-label">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Alumno.Email" required />
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Guardar Cambios</button>
                                <a asp-action="AlumnoLista" asp-controller="Alumno" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Volver a la lista</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#modalAlumno" data-bs-toggle="modal">Volver al primero</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

He probado distintas maneras pero no logro q la vista "DetalleAlumno" ejecute el modal.

Alguien podrá ayudarme a resolverlo ?

Comment: que ves aca? @ViewBag.Accion??

Comment: En el controller tengo 2 ViewBag, uno para "agregar Alumno" y otro para "Editar Alumno". Solo subi el de "agregar Alumno" q es en el q estoy trabado. Desde el controller viene con ese ViewBag y entra en el @if (ViewBag.Accion == "Agregar Alumno"). En este caso el ViewBag viene con "Agregar Alumno"

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir un Modal de Bootstrap automaticamente cuando se carga la página, debes colocar un script como este:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => { //cuando el DOM ha cargado
  const modal = document.getElementById('exampleModal'); // buscamos por el ID del modal 
  if(modal){ //si existe el elemento, aplicamos la API de bootstrap para abrirlo
    const btModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modal);
    btModal.show()
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```